# convolve unevenly spaced vectors in scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, convolution

I have a measured spectrum, i.e. a 1d array `spec` with `spec.shape = (n, )`. The individual points correspond to unevenly spaced wavelengths, stored in a 1d array `wl` with `wl.shape = (n, )`. Now I need to convolve this spectrum with a Gaussian function of predefined FWHM.

How can I do this using numpy/scipy?

Currently, I have this:

```
fwhm = .22
gaussian_window = scipy.signal.gaussian(spec.size, std=fwhm/2.3548201)
result = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(spec, gaussian_window)
```

However, this doesn't take into account the uneven spacing of the input data at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could just [interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) your unevenly spaced input data onto a uniform grid. If the spectrum should be smooth then provided you choose the same grid as that used by your Gaussian window you should be okay.